# basic logic of lock - mutual exclusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, redis, mutual-exclusion

I'm struggling with the logic of lock for mutual exclusion; Here Im checking if the key is taken or not, if not we take it and when done release it; but could you please help me how I can have a loop to check the key until it becomes available?

```
rdb.setnx(lockkey, 'taken', function (err, lockvalue) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else if (lockvalue == 1) {
        // You have the lock; process it
        //Release the key when you are done:
        rdb.del(lockkey);
    } else if (lockvalue == 0) {
        // Key is taken by someone else; so how can I have a loop to check until key is available to take? 
    }
});
```

Your help is appreciated :-)

**UPDATED:**

Thanks so much Adeneco for the answer; I have always been confused with the logic of self executing function; so if I want to pass timeout could you please confirm my logic is right:

```
n=1;
(function rec(n) {
    rdb.setnx(lockkey, 'taken', function (err, lockvalue) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else if (lockvalue == 1) {
            // You have the lock; process it
            //Release the key when you are done:
            rdb.del(lockkey);
        } else if (lockvalue == 0) {
            // Key is taken by someone else; try again
            setTimeout(function(){ rec(n++); }, 30<<n);            
        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a recursive function, and just call it again

```
(function rec() {
    rdb.setnx(lockkey, 'taken', function (err, lockvalue) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else if (lockvalue == 1) {
            // You have the lock; process it
            //Release the key when you are done:
            rdb.del(lockkey);
        } else if (lockvalue == 0) {
            // Key is taken by someone else; try again
            rec();
        }
    });
})();
```

a timeout can be used to delay the recursive calls if neccessary

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer; I have always been confused with the logic of self executing function; so if I want to pass timeout could you please confirm my logic is right (I added my logic in my answer section)

Comment: Yes, that seems about right, the bitwise shift is clever

Comment: Was just writing that, you can pass `n` at the bottom

Comment: You've defined it globally in your code, so just removing the local argument that would work as well, so you don't have to, but you probably should. Also I'd do `rec(++n)` otherwise you're stuck at `1` and it never increments

Comment: For a more resilient solution, you may want to use this algorithm instead: http://redis.io/topics/distlock